# why is overloading methods recommended over using the instanceof operator in java methods?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have a method that I wrote below. Its using a ton of instanceof logic but atleast I don't have 4 overloaded versions of the same method. What can go wrong in the below method? Why is overloading methods preferred over using instanceof?

```
public static <T extends Number> Number SumVector(List<? extends Number> vector){

        if (vector.get(0) instanceof Integer){
            Integer retVal = 0;
            for (Number val : vector){
                retVal = retVal+ ((Integer) val).intValue();
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        if (vector.get(0) instanceof Double){
            Double retVal = (double) 0;
            for (Number val : vector){
                retVal = retVal+ ((Double) val).doubleValue();
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        if (vector.get(0) instanceof Float){
            Float retVal = (float) 0.0;
            for (Number val : vector){
                retVal = retVal+ ((Float) val).floatValue();
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: There's an important pattern in software design called [High Cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). The code you've proposed doesn't have high cohesion.

Comment: "At least I don't have 4 overloaded versions of the same method." I don't know why you consider that an advantage. You still have four versions of the same code. They are just all inside a single method. It's not an advantage, and the runtime `instanceof` test could have been done by the compiler if you had used method overloading.

Comment: @EJP: I was not aware that the compiler would turn my overloaded method in to an instanceof check. Could you please elaborate on your comment some more? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Architecturally, I would suggest that you make your class abstract and create specific subclasses that handle the concrete cases. This would alow you to both skip checking the types manually and also add new operations easily.

Keep in mind that doing the checks manually is perfectly fine in your case,  as the number of Number subclasses is not expected to change...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use of interfaces and concrete classes in this case?

Comment: I would create an interface (f.e. `NumberVector<T extends Number> extends List<T>`) that defines specific methods that need to be implemented by subclasses (f.e `T sum()`); then create concrete subclasses (f.e. `IntVector extends ArrayList<Integer> implements NumberVector<Integer>`, `FloatVector` etc). Keep in mind that this presupposes that you are in control of all the locations where such vectors are generated...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find it makes code much more readable if you have multiple overloaded functions (in your case one for each number type). However what you did is perfectly valid. Its really up to you. Think about who is going to be using the function, is it just you, in which case do whatever you feel like because you know what data is going to be going in, or is it going to be part of a library in which case you might want only certain things to be allowed to input. In your example again it shouldn't matter because you said

```
<T extends Number>
```

so it won't take anything that's not a number. The norm however is to use multiple functions just for ease of reading. Hope that was clear!